# React: Redundant Lifecycle Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have multiple react components with the same lifecycle hooks. Is there a good design practice for dealing with this?

At first I tried to use composition. Creating a wrapper for my child components. I then tried to create a lifecycle hook for the wrapper with componentWillMount.

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
   componentWillMount() {
      if(this.props.status == "not logged in") browserHistory.push("/login")
   }
   render() {
      return {
         <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      }
   }
}
```

However, I then realized that componentWillMount only gets triggered when the wrapper is initially rendered. So any changes to child components doesn't trigger the componentWillMount. A solution could be a lifecycle hook that triggers when a child component changes, but I've looked and I don't think it exists.

Another solution is using inheritance and creating a parent class that defines a lifecycle hook.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
   componentWillMount() {
      if(this.props.status == "not logged in") browserHistory.push("/login")
   }
}
```

And then I could create components that inherit this with:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  ...
}
```

However I heard inheritance with React components are a bad idea due to performance and collisions.

Any thoughts? Or perhaps I need to use redundant code? Just looking for an elegant solution.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds you're describing a use case for a HOC (Higher-Order Component), whereby it's able to check the login status for a given user. Take a peak at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html, it has some decent examples.

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try using the new React Hooks way of doing this, the following custom hook would do what you're looking for

```
const routeLoggedOutUser = loginStatus => {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (loginStatus === "not logged in")
        browserHistory.push("/login");
    },
    [loginStatus]
  );
};
```

You just call the custom hook in the relevant function components like so:

```
function Inner({ status }) {
  routeLoggedOutUser(status);
  return <div>A component with status {status}</div>;
}
```

Routing based on this condition is a bit iffy though, you might want to re-think exactly where in the app this login status update is received so the re-routing logic only occurs once.

Sandbox code to take a closer look [right here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2j9pxj64r).

Answer (score 0):

React Hooks is a new API designed to solve this problem (along with others). It makes reusing stateful logic between components easier. In your case, you could write a custom hook called `useLogoutStatus`. The convention is to start hooks with the word `use` so that the hooks ESLint plugin can tell that it's a hook and ensure that usage of that hook follows the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

```
function useLogoutStatus(loginStatus) {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (loginStatus === 'not logged in') {
        browserHistory.push('/login');
      }
    },
    [loginStatus], // This tells React to only run `useEffect` when `loginStatus` has changed.
  );
};
```

And in your components, you could do:

```
function Profile(props) {
  useLogoutStatus(props.status);

  return ...;
}

function Feed(props) {
  useLogoutStatus(props.status);

  return ...;
}
```